# Responsive iframe with varying aspect ratio content - have solution looking for better one

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I have a requirement for a responsive iframe. I have found many solutions for embeding videos (and Bootstrap even has classes for this specific case) but I'm embeding a form which itself is responsive (This is a Global Payments / Realex Paymenmts HPP card paymemt form if anyone know it).

So, the aspect ration of the form changes based on its size and also what the user does - for example it gets longer to display error messages.

Also, as can be seen the initial  content is the iframe is just "Please wait..." and the thoird party form is loaded via javascript.

I have modified the video embeding method by adding progressive media queries to increase padding as the device gets smaller and thus the form longer, to avoid scroll bars. It seems to work well, but there must be a more efficient/simple/elegant solution?

HTML

```
<div class='hpp_iframe_wrapper'>
<iframe class='hpp_iframe' id='realex_hpp_iframe' name='realex_hpp_iframe' srcdoc='<p>Please wait ...</p>'></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
  position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 80%;
}




.hpp_iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}



@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 90%;
  }
}



@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 100%;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 130%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 145%;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 160%;
  }
}



@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 185%;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 200%;
  }
}



@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 220%;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 240%;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 340px) {
  .hpp_iframe_wrapper  {
    padding-top: 260%;
  }
}
```